# group by full name having different ids associated

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table client it has the following columns

```
id  first_name  last_name  clientid
1   tom         saver      1590
2   john        saver      1590
3   help        Desk       0
4   tom         saver      0
5   hello       world      1590
```

I want to return a new list which is like this using LINQ

```
full_name    assClientids
tom saver    1590, 0
john saver   0
help desk    0
hello world  1590
```

I am unable to group by using the full name in LINQ

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: When you say "unable to group by... full name" do you mean that you cannot get it working correctly, or that you are disallowed in some way?

Comment: I cannot get it working correctly

Answer (score 2):

I wrote up a quick console app to show.  See below classes, this should get you what you are looking for.

```
public class DbViewModel
{
         public long TotalClients { get; set; }
    public long FilteredCLients { get; set; }
    public List<Client> Clients{ get; set; }
    public List<int> AssociatedClientIds { get; set; }
}
public class Client
{

    public Client() {}
    public ClientLink ClientLink { get; set; }

    public const string LastNameDisplayName = "Last Name";
    public const int    LastNameMaxLength    =  100;
    public const string LastNameMaxLengthStr = "100";
    //[MaxLength(LastNameMaxLength)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public const string FirstNameDisplayName = "First Name";
    public const int    FirstNameMaxLength    =  30;
    public const string FirstNameMaxLengthStr = "30";
    //[MaxLength(FirstNameMaxLength)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public const string MiddleNameDisplayName = "Middle Name";
    public const int    MiddleNameMaxLength    =  30;
    public const string MiddleNameMaxLengthStr = "30";
    //[MaxLength(MiddleNameMaxLength)]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public const string SuffixDisplayName = "Suffix";
    public const int    NameSuffixMaxLength    =  10;
    public const string NameSuffixMaxLengthStr = "10";
    //[MaxLength(NameSuffixMaxLength)]
    public string NameSuffix { get; set; }


    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return NameFormatter.Format(LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, NameSuffix);
        }
    }


}
public class ClientLink  
{
    public long ClientId { get; set; }
    private List<ClientAddress> address = new List<ClientAddress>();

    public ClientLink()
    {
    }      
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<DbModel> dbModels = DbModel.GetModels();

        List<DbViewModel> viewModels = dbModels.GroupBy(x => x.first_name.ToLower() + ' ' + x.last_name.ToLower()).Select(fullNameGrouping =>
            new DbViewModel()
            {
                full_name = fullNameGrouping.Key,
                clientIds = fullNameGrouping.Select(x => x.clientId).ToList()
            }).ToList();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is your `Client` class

```
public class Client
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
}
```

We can do a `GroupBy` on concatenated first and last names.

```
var clients = new List<Client>
{
    new Client() { ID = 1, FirstName = "Tom", LastName = "Saver", ClientID = 1590 },
    new Client() { ID = 2, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Saver", ClientID = 1590 },
    new Client() { ID = 3, FirstName = "Help", LastName = "Desk", ClientID = 0 },
    new Client() { ID = 4, FirstName = "Tom", LastName = "Saver", ClientID = 0 },
    new Client() { ID = 5, FirstName = "Hello", LastName = "World", ClientID = 1590 }
};

var groupByFullName = clients.GroupBy(x => string.Concat(x.FirstName, " ", x.LastName));
```

Now your `groupByFullName` collection is grouped by full name.